# Authenticate server (peer) with SSL

Tags: c, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I would want my C/C++ client to authenticate the server via SSL.
I first downloaded the certificate file from the server with
`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect www.openssl.org:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > mycertfile.pem`

Then in my application I do the following API invocations (pseudo code):

```
// Register the error strings for libcrypto & libssl
SSL_load_error_strings();
// Register the available ciphers and digests
SSL_library_init();
// New context saying we are a client, and using SSL 2 or 3
ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
// load the certificate
if(!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "mycertfile.pem", 0))
  ...
// Create an SSL struct for the connection
ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
// Connect the SSL struct to our pre-existing TCP/IP socket connection
if (!SSL_set_fd(ssl, sd))
  ...
// Initiate SSL handshake
if(SSL_connect(ssl) != 1)
  ...
// form this point onwards the SSL connection is established and works
// perfectly, I would be able to send and receive encrypted data
// **Crucial point now**
// Get certificate (it works)
X509 *cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl);
if(cert) {
  // the below API returns code 19
  const long cert_res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
  if(cert_res == X509_V_OK) {
    printf("Certificate verified!\n");
  }
  X509_free(cert);
}
```

Above code works fine if I don't mind checking the certificate and I'm just interested in an encrypted connection.
Problem with it is that when I try to verify the authenticity of the server, I *do* get the certificate from `SSL_get_peer_certificate` but then the verification of results doesn't work *even* if I've just downloaded the certificate 5 minutes before.

What am I doing wrong?

All this is on Ubuntu 12.04.03 x86-64 with gcc and *openssl*.

Thanks,
Ema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only call `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` if you have a more complete set of CA certificates than what OpenSSL already provides, or if you are connecting to a server that has used a non-standard CA to sign its cert, and for which you have the CA certificate to verify the server cert. Otherwise, you should call `SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths()` instead.

```
// load the certificate^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H^H CA trust-store
if(!SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths(ctx))
  ...
```

On a side note, your program had another error. You passed the wrong pointer to `SSL_get_verify_result()`. Instead of passing in a `SSL_CTX *`, you should pass in the `SSL *`. The compiler should have warned you about this error.

```
  const long cert_res = SSL_get_verify_result(ssl);
```

Comment: A [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/QcR4Q8pG) of a simplified version of your program that I used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate you just downloaded should have been signed by a certificate authority (CA). You need to load the certificate of the CA (or the root CA) and not the certificate itself. Since you loaded the server's certificate directly into the `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations`, the verification routine `SSL_get_verify_result` returned with a failure code. Most likely the verification code must have been 19 (`X509_V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`).

That said, OpenSSL comes with a built-in set of CAs (and root CAs) that you can use in your client application. The path to these certificates, on a Linux distribution, is typically /etc/ssl/certs. So, you can try changing your `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations` as below:

```
if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, NULL, "/etc/ssl/certs"))
   ...
```

Of course, this assumes that /etc/ssl/certs exists and has the relevant certificates (one of which signed the server certificate). If you are authenticating a well known host, you will most likely find the CA in /etc/ssl/certs.